# All Text appears in uppercase in Edittext

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have a strange problem. Whatever in Edittext ,  all letters are autocapitalize. I don't want that. I want text to appear same as user types which is lower and uppercase both.

Here is my code

```java
          <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="?     android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:cursorVisible="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                             android:hint="Feedback"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:id="@+id/feedback_input" />
```

Comment: Please, post also your code. The xml looks just fine or at least I don't see anything that would lead to the described behaviour.

Comment: It might be your keyboard not code problem

Comment: @AntonisRadz agree with u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `android:textAllCaps="false"` in your edit text.

Comment: Please refrain from adding "it may help you" to all of your posts. No-one posts thinking their answer will not help.